# Isint Memcached doing the same job as Buffer pool in Innodb?

Tags: mysql, caching, memcached, buffer, innodb

This is what I understand it as:

**Buffer Pool in Innodb**: This stores the index and data from Sql table and caches it for future queries so it doesn't need to bother Mysql all the time.

**Memcached**: this is used to store the data received from Innodb and caches it so it doesn't need to keep asking Innodb each time.

Aren't they both doing the same thing I.e caching the response in Ram so it is faster and reduces I/o and sql parsing? Then why add another layer of memcached on top of Innodb Buffer pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Buffer pool** is managed by InnoDB. Everything needed to do queries must be in the buffer pool so data already in there gets evicted if needed when new data is read from disk to be used in the current query.

Joins between tables is still done and can be costly, even if the tables are in the buffer pool.

**Memcached** on the other hand is a key-value store. No relational operations can be performed on data stored there, just inserts and retrievals. It is also distributed making it possible to build huge clusters.

Typically the results of long running or heavy queries are stored in memcached for a period of time, taking load of the database.

Comment: Thank you for your response @AndreasWederbrand I am slowly beginning to understand the difference. However I am still not clear what memcached really store. Can you tell me what "key value store" means in dummies language? When I read in wiki and other pages it explains about associative array of Key value pair etc.. but finding it hard to grasp what data it really is.

Comment: Let's say in a real life example, I have a web page that is listing the recent 10 article titles and descriptions. So the query will fetch the results from Innodb buffer pool where the data is stored in tabular model (upto this I can understand). So after query matches and the data is returned to memcached, is it this "returned data" is what actually stored inside memcached? Is key value actually means the data that comes from a query? Or how does memcached break this returned data results in Key value store?

Comment: Key value store is just like a hash map with a key and value. Typically you would build a key based on the incoming request and then store the entire result in memcached once fetched. On subsequent requests generate the same key and check if memcached have a value stored for it. If so, just return that instead.

Comment: Right... It makes perfect sense now. In this case, I feel it might be better to allocate a bigger ram for memcached so it can hold much data instead of starting to delete the old ones. From your answer I can clearly understand how memcached differ from Innodb buffer pool. Thank you so much for putting it in a simpler way to understand. :)

Comment: Can't you just make a key-value MySQL table, and load that table into the buffer pool instead of using Memcached? Why use Memcached at all?